# Can't align button to the bottom left of the screen - React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I would like to position my button to the bottom left of the screen. I have tried using `bottom: 0` and `left: 0`, but that did not do anything. I researched a bit and discovered that I need to set the `position: 'absolute'`. However, when I do this, my button disappears completely.

How can I position by the button to the bottom left of the screen?

Here is my code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button,Alert, TouchableOpacity,Image } from 'react-native'

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: '#375D81', flex: 1}}>
         <View style = {styles.container}>
           <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonText} onPress={() => { Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')}}>
             <Text>
              Button
             </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 main: {
   backgroundColor: 'blue'
 },
 container: {
  alignItems: 'center',
 },
  buttonText: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      padding: 25,      
      borderColor: 'black',
      backgroundColor: '#C4D7ED',
      borderRadius: 15,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      position: 'absolute'
   }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => Project);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to flex your container. Add: `flex: 1` in there and you're all good:

```
container: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  flex: 1
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set a width and height to your button then:

```
 justifyContent: 'flex-end'
```

That's it

> App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

> styles.js

```js
export default {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },

  button: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 70,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 20,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
};
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

See Expo Snack: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/button-left](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/button-left)

Answer (score 0):

React-native elements are "rendered" from the top left when defining their position `absolute`ly. This means when you are defining `bottom: 0` and `left: 0`, this is rendering the item where you want horizontally, but vertically it will be off the screen. switch to

```
position 'absolute',
bottom: 100,
left: 0,
```

This should be what you are looking for

Comment: It still results in the same outcome, with a blank screen. Even with experimenting with the values.

Comment: I found the solution by removing the view with the style 'container'. If someone could just answer why this works.